Skew Jack polynomial
I found the following formula in an article for the skew Jack polynomials:
$$
J_{\lambda\setminus\mu} = \sum_\nu\frac{\langle J_\lambda, J_\mu J_\nu\rangle}{\langle J_\nu, J_\nu\rangle}J_\nu.
$$
But the paper does not say over which integer partitions $\nu$ the summation is taken. Would you know? The only thing I know is that $\nu$ must be a partition of $|\lambda|-|\mu|$ but I believe not all such partitions.

It might help if you included a link to the article in question, or at least a reference to it, rather than leaving it to us to search the literature.
